# jQuery ajax call fail in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer-8

I have a script that grabs content from another page on my server and returns the text. Everything works fine in all major browsers except for IE8 and down, which doesn't do anything. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
$.ajax({
  url: clickedURL,
  dataType: "html",
  cache: false,
  dataFilter: function(data, type) {
    if (type==="html") {
        return data.replace(/<script.*?>([\w\W\d\D\s\S\0\n\f\r\t\v\b\B]*?)<\/script>/gi, '');
    }
    return data;
    },
    success: function(html) {
      var divContent = $("<div/>").append(html).find(".ajax-specific").html();
      $(".single-course").html(divContent);
    }
});
```

Comment: Providing error message would help...

Comment: That's one huge regex. Why don't you just use `/<script.*?>.*<\/script>`/gi?

Comment: have you tried registering an ajaxError function? http://api.jquery.com/ajaxError/ That way you can get some info from the jquery XMLHttpRequest object

Comment: @Blender Yes that sure looks nicer, thanks!

Comment: @ShaneA It didn't give me any errors I'm afraid

Comment: verify that the html being returned is all valid html. IE seems to choke on invalid html more often. (watch quotes!)

Comment: @KevinB Any idea if the doctype and html5 elements might have anything to do with it? (before I co changing the entire document)

Comment: show a sample of clickedURL value

Comment: @tsimbidis if you're trying to select them, yes it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

Turn on JS debugging in IE and check where it fails. If it doesn't help, use some HTTP debugger like [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to inspect request/response. Maybe there is something wrong in it.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that it gives me nothing. The ajax call is inside a click handler and I know that the clickedURL updates perfectly fine.

Comment: Tried Fiddler and saw that it actually got a 200 code, so I tried logging out the html result and found out that it's all there. It seems like it fails to append the result.